# How to give npmrc file location in pom.xml

Tags: java, reactjs, maven, spring-boot

I'm building a app that is the combination of webservices and reactjs. Webservices are in created using spring boot. And I have local repository for maven, react. So I can't download the file from the web. I have configured npmrc file.

But When I try to build the code I get the error. Because the code is downloading the packages from https://registry.npmjs.org/react-scripts.

> 61 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect
>   ETIMEDOUT 168.29.59.11:443
>   62 info attempt registry request try #3 at 8:12:09 PM

Is there any way that at the time of building the code, Maven use the path that I configured in the npmrc file?

Comment: Try exec-maven-plugin. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771693/passing-working-directory-to-npm-in-exec-maven-plugin

Comment: Is your `.npmrc` file in the same directory as `package.json`? And does your npmrc file point to your local repository like `@myscope:registry=https://mycustomregistry.example.org`?

Comment: yes, it is in same folder as package.json and point to my local repository.